# MySQL: Returning records from the current month and previous 3 months

Tags: mysql, date, filter

I'm using PHP/MySQL booking system and i'm using a Google Line Chart to try and display the gross sales from the current month, and also the previous 3 months.

Each booking has a date in the standard phpmyadmin "date" format, so yyyy:mm:dd.

So, im looking to get 4 results from 4 queries, each query filtering out a certain month and grabbing the sum of each booking from that month.

My question is, how can i distinguish between the months in the query? How would i structure the query?

Comment: Example query and example code?

Comment: the table only consists of a booking, date and fee. I simply need to grab bookings depending on the month entered in the query, but i dont know how to structure the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the title:

```
select * from bookings where MONTH(CURDATE())=MONTH(booking_date);
select * from bookings where MONTH(booking_date) > MONTH(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and < MONTH(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

For simple per-month searches you can use the following:

```
Select * from bookings where MONTHNAME(booking_date)='July' and YEAR(booking_date)=2013;
```

Or:

```
Select * from bookings where MONTH(booking_date)=7 and YEAR(booking_date)=2013;
```

Also since you've already got the months, you could do this (this method requires that you maintain a table of ending dates for each month an compensate for leap year though):

```
select * from bookings where booking_date>'2013-06-30' AND booking_date<'2013-08-01';
```

Comment: There is no double equal in MySQL so you should remove it. You also don't need quotes around integers in this context.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Yeah, noticed it about 2 seconds after I posted.

Answer (score 1):

In first place, excuse my english....

I know this is old thread and cant comment but, @AbsoluteƵERØ, that answer apply to the current month, in example, if i got records of July in 2013-2014-2015, the query will return the records on the month for those years.... To avoid that and using your posted code:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(booking_date) AND YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(booking_date);
```

Note: if use the "name form" and specify the year there's no problem, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(booking_date) AND YEAR(booking_date) = 2013;
```